# Align like button comment dialog box

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Is there anyway to align the comment dialog that appears after clicking the "Like" button to the left rather than to the right.

I would like to do that to fix a problem I am having with multiple "Like" buttons in  the content of a page in a masonry layout. The Dialog button is hidden behind elements that are to the right of it.

You can see an example [here](http://goo.gl/0Rty5).

Comment: This seems to be a stubborn issue! Would love to fix this in some of my situations.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
<center>
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1">
</script><iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FID_HERE&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;width=50&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:50px; height:30px;" allowtransparency="false"></iframe>
```

Comment: I unfortunately can't test and confirm it on the project I was working on when the questions was asked as it no longer online and I no longer have access to the code.